# Parameterizing a freemarker builtin

Tags: freemarker, built-in

Can the builtin part of a expression in freemarker be parameterized?
If so, how?

For example, a date can be formatted with the following builtins:

```
${openingTime?string.short}
${openingTime?string.medium}
${openingTime?string.long}
${openingTime?string.full}
```

Can the string.short/string.medium/... builtin names be parameterized too?

For example, I'd like to do something like:

```
${openingTime?${mydatefmt}}
```

where mydatefmt is 'string.short' or any valid format.

That would make it easily possible to change the date formats on a freemarker page.

I want to limit the change to a page/file and not apply globally.

Does something like this need to be put into a Freemarker macro that might anticipate all possible types of date formats that might be needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the formatting pattern explicitly : `${openingTime?string("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzzz")}`

The date format can be a expression, for example : `${openingTime?string(mydatefmt)}`.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is using `openingTime?string(pattern)`, where pattern can be any kind of expression that evaluates to a string. But it's quite verbose and somewhat slow, as the patter will be re-parsed again and again.

Another approach is setting the `date_format`, `time_format` and `datetime_format` FreeMarker settings, and then just write `${openingTime}`. (Actually, if `openingTime` isn't a `javax.sql` subclass of `java.util.Date`, you have to write `${openingTime?datetime}`, because the Java API doesn't know the difference date-time, time and date-only, but this is another story.) FreeMarker settings can be set globally (better said, on `Configuration`-level), on template-level (but you don't do that usually), or on the `Environment`. See http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_config_settings.html. The last can be done in FTL too, like with `<#setting datetime_format = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzzz'>`.